# Preselected option by ng-init doesn't work in ngOptions | AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

I have object `product = {id: "759", name: "someName", category_id: "139", cartridge_type: 2 ...}` in my angular controller.

Why preselected option in `ngOptions` doesn't work? Select renders empty option as if  `product.cartridge_type` would be `null`.

**HTML**

```
<select class="form-control"
        id="cartridge_type"
        name="cartridge_type"

        ng-init="product.cartridge_type=product.cartridge_type||cartridgeTypeScope[0]"
        ng-model="product.cartridge_type"
        ng-options="cartridge_type.id as cartridge_type.name for cartridge_type in cartridgeTypeScope">

    <option value="">Select type</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
$http.get('someApiPath').success(function(data) {
    $scope.product = data[0];
    console.log( $scope.product );
});

$scope.cartridgeTypeScope = [
    {
        id: 0,
        name  : '-'
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        name  : 'cartridgeType1'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name  : 'cartridgeType2'
    }
]
```

Comment: try to use ng-init before <select> in any other html tag

Comment: @ShubhamNigam you mean set it in controller?

Comment: <div ng-init="initialization" ><select>..</select>

Comment: @ShubhamNigam I've done as you've adviced, it doesn't help..

Comment: if you as are using product.cartridge_type as a model it will store id of selected value ,you all need to do is either put cartridgeTypeScope[0].id in ng-init or remove 'id as' from ng-options

Comment: **This isn't the appropriate use for ng-init**.  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit#!/.  ng-init is a directive which has a higher than 0 priority level to ensure that it executes after certain other actions, which is ***only*** appropriate for ng-repeat.  It *may* work with other properties, or it may fail completely, due to it's late run based on it's priority.

Comment: @Claies ok, then how one could make preselect in ngOptions?

Comment: select the default option when your controller initializes.  when the dropdown is populated, it will be pre-set to whatever value the `ng-model` variable is already set to.

Comment: @Claies you mean I need to remove ng-init from select and it must work? But it doesn't. Because of that I add the ngInit directive in hope it helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just simple use `cartridgeTypeScope[0].id` in ng-init

```
ng-init="product.cartridge_type=product.cartridge_type||cartridgeTypeScope[0].id"
```

Thing is that you are using `cartridge_type.id as cartridge_type.name` which is expecting id in the select but in ng-init you are providing it complete object (`cartridgeTypeScope[0]`). 
So it is not selecting your option value.

Alternatively you can do
 You can use same ng-init but remove `cartridge_type.id as` from your `ng-options`

```
ng-init="product.cartridge_type=product.cartridge_type||cartridgeTypeScope[0]"

 ng-options="cartridge_type.name for cartridge_type in cartridgeTypeScope"
```

Hope It help :)

**UPDATE**

For controller default option you need to do

```
  $scope.product={
    "cartridge_type":2
  }
```

**UPADTE 2**:-
For $http:-

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hGFEntHWWC5gyvKmIudB?p=preview)

Comment: Firstly, thank you for so detailed response. It's odd, but both your advices don't work for me. Can't figure out why..

Comment: HAve you checked the plunker ? Can you create fiddle or plunker for the same ?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work. When I simply add `$scope.product.cartridge_type = 2` to the controller in plunker the select does not preselect the proper option.

Comment: @Alliswell I Update my answer please check :)

Comment: I've checked it. You've removed `ng-init` directive as I see and it works fine. I've made the same changes in my code but still can't make it work..

Comment: Can you please replicate it on plunker or fiddle ?

Comment: All the same as in your plunker except I get product object via `$http.get` request

Comment: by the way, it must work and it works fine without `ng-init` )